# if i have 4 cells and load the images for 4 cells, but all the 4 images are overlapped only at the last cell

Tags: swift, uicollectionviewcell

I need to load the images in each cells and return UIcollectionview Cell. but all the images are overlapped in the last cell..

When i debugged the image is set in the completion handler and it sets the image after the cells are actually returned..

since i am using self in the completed block of the sd_setImage, which indicates the last cell when the completion block starts executing, so all the images are set in the same cell, i guess..

either i should set the image before the cell is returned, or int he completion block while it is setting it should have the proper reference to the cell. how to do that....

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: CELL_IDENTIFIER, for: indexPath) as? CollectionViewCell

        var row = 0
        row = indexPath.row
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        var imgURL: String? = nil
        if let object = (dataSource[row] as? [AnyHashable : Any])?["src"] {
            imgURL = "\(object)"
        }
        let url = URL(string: imgURL ?? "")

        imageView.sd_setImage(with: url, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"), completed: { [weak self] (image, error, cacheType, imageURL) in

            self?.cell?.cellImageView.image = imageView.image

        })

        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        var shoptitle: String? = nil
        if let object = (dataSource[row] as? [AnyHashable : Any])?["shop_name"] {
            shoptitle = "\(object)"
        }

        cell?.txtDescription.text = shoptitle
        cell?.shareIcon.tag = indexPath.item
        cell?.cellImageView.tag = indexPath.item
        cell?.cellImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        cell?.shareIcon.addTarget(self, action: #selector(click(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        cell?.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
        cell?.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 1.0, height: 1.0)
        cell?.layer.shadowRadius = 10.0
        cell?.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor

        return cell!
    }
```

Comment: I don't get why you have used `self` for the cell. If I'm not mistaken, you can use the cell as is inside the handler's block without the need for `self`. Also, if this code runs without errors, your VC must have some property named 'cell', which you are updating on every callback

Comment: `self?.cell?` Why?` self?.cell?.cellImageView.image = imageView.image` => ` cell?.cellImageView.image = imageView.image`

Comment: try to make cell object in "cellForItemAt" method.

Comment: @LokSN if i am not using self then i am getting a compiler error "Reference to property 'cell' in closure requires explicit 'self.' to make capture semantics explicit". thats the reason i auto fixed the suggestion given by xcode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If its not work than just set image to `cell.cellImageView` like this :

```
cell.cellImageView.sd_setImage(with: url, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"), completed: { 
[weak self] (image, error, cacheType, imageURL) 
in

})
```

So You Complete Code will be like this :

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: CELL_IDENTIFIER, for: indexPath) as? CollectionViewCell

        var row = 0
        row = indexPath.row
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        var imgURL: String? = nil
        if let object = (dataSource[row] as? [AnyHashable : Any])?["src"] {
            imgURL = "\(object)"
        }
        let url = URL(string: imgURL ?? "")

        cell.cellImageView.sd_setImage(with: url, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"), completed: { 
[weak self] (image, error, cacheType, imageURL) 
in

})

        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        var shoptitle: String? = nil
        if let object = (dataSource[row] as? [AnyHashable : Any])?["shop_name"] {
            shoptitle = "\(object)"
        }

        cell?.txtDescription.text = shoptitle
        cell?.shareIcon.tag = indexPath.item
        cell?.cellImageView.tag = indexPath.item
        cell?.cellImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        cell?.shareIcon.addTarget(self, action: #selector(click(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        cell?.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
        cell?.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 1.0, height: 1.0)
        cell?.layer.shadowRadius = 10.0
        cell?.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor

        return cell!
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

did you tried to remove this line of code ?

`self?.cell?.cellImageView.image = imageView.image`

Comment: i didnt try it. but Ekramul Hoque solution worked for me. thank you

Answer (score 0):

**Please try below code with make Cell object in "cellForItemAt" method**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: CELL_IDENTIFIER, for: indexPath) as? CollectionViewCell

    var imgURL: String? = nil
    if let object = (dataSource[indexPath.item] as? [AnyHashable : Any])?["src"] {
        imgURL = "\(object)"
    }

    cell?.cellImageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: imgURL ?? ""), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"), completed: { [weak self] (image, error, cacheType, imageURL) in
    })

    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    var shoptitle: String? = nil
    if let object = (dataSource[indexPath.item] as? [AnyHashable : Any])?["shop_name"] {
        shoptitle = "\(object)"
    }

    cell?.txtDescription.text = shoptitle
    cell?.shareIcon.tag = indexPath.item
    cell?.cellImageView.tag = indexPath.item
    cell?.cellImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    cell?.shareIcon.addTarget(self, action: #selector(click(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    cell?.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
    cell?.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 1.0, height: 1.0)
    cell?.layer.shadowRadius = 10.0
    cell?.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor

    return cell!
}
```

Comment: Thank rohit. i just tried Ekramul Hoque's solution and it worked for me. thanks for your time.